# Unable to create Spring Project

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-mvc

I've installed SpringSource Tool Source (STS) for eclipse as it is in my installed section, shown in following image :
[image]

Now When I create New Project I'm unable to create "Spring Project" from menu by navigating File>New Project>

[image]

It only shows legacy and starter Spring projects.

Why I'm unable to create "Spring Project" what I'm missing here?

Then By searching on google I found that I've to create spring legacy project and then I've to select spring MVC Project. I've done the same but ended in so many error and I don't know how to resolve them as shown in the following image:[image]

what step I'm missing here??

Comment: Hi, I don' t know so much about eclipse plugins, but I think that should be a good option, use start.spring.io to create your project and import it into your IDE.

Comment: how?? I'm completely new at java and eclipse and spring and everything ;) please let me know how to use start.spring.io??

Answer (score 0):

Open the website https://start.spring.io/

1. Select if you want generate maven or gradle project
2. Select the last stable version of spring boot
3. Write Group and Artifact names to your project
4. Choose dependencies (this is a autocomplete text box, test write "Web")
5. Click in the button Generate Project (it will download a zip with your project)
6. Unpack
7. Import the project in the Eclipse IDE

I think this can help.